# Google Analytics API Error with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm following this example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

And when I excecute I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3AXXXX&start-date=2015-10-26&end-date=2015-10-26&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3Ahostname%2Cga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3Aday%3D%3D26:
>   (500) There was an internal error.' in
>   /expert/htwebs/bbdd.introl.es/docs/recogida/v2/administracion/google2/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /expert/htwebs/bbdd.introl.es/docs/recogida/v2/administracion/google2/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /expert/htwebs/bbdd.introl.es/docs/recogida/v2/administracion/google2/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /expert/htwebs/bbdd.introl.es/docs/recogida/v2/administracion/google2/
>   in
>   /expert/htwebs/bbdd.introl.es/docs/recogida/v2/administracion/google2/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 110

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid Auth Token?

Comment: I do the authentication by the login page. I don't know how to generate the token by code...

Comment: You need to look up the OAuth process and go through that first. Basically you need to create an app in the Developer console, then you send a user to google's login, then they redirect you back with a code. You then use that code to request a token. It is pretty standard OAuth2.0. Once you have that token you include it in your requests to the API.

Comment: But how can I create this token?

Comment: As I said you need to go through the entire OAuth process.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app